# Why is the combustion temperature in a turbojet engine kept low?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine, temperature

Why the temperature of hot gas entering the turbine is maintained  far below the adiabatic combustion temperature?

Comment: Because there is no material to build a turbine stage able to sustain the combustion temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the fuel-air mixture in a turbine is [much leaner](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/10034/if-jets-carried-pure-o2-to-use-for-combustion-would-they-be-more-efficient/10036#10036) than what it would be for a [stoichiometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoichiometry) combustion. It needs to stay lean to restrict the maximum gas temperature inside the engine - higher temperatures lead to exponentially shorter lives of the turbine components.