# What different intake designs are there, and what are their pros and cons?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, engine-design, inlet

I noticed that over the years (on fighter jets specifically) there have been many different methods of directing air into the engines. Primarily, the nose-intake, side intake, and underbody intakes have been very popular with many different designs.

Could somebody explain what the pros and cons behind each type are?

Comment: [This may answer the question for you.](http://sturgeonshouse.ipbhost.com/topic/690-a-quick-explanation-of-combat-aircraft-air-intakes/) And this is a [possible dupe of at least part of it.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39425/what-is-the-difference-between-side-by-side-vs-under-cockpit-engine-intakes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the nose of the Mig-21 shaped so differently compared to other fighter aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/why-is-the-nose-of-the-mig-21-shaped-so-differently-compared-to-other-fighter-ai)

Comment: What? @ymb1 that doesn't explain like 8/9's of my question. There are tens of different intake designs please if you want to call a dupe read my whole question and figure out the answer first. And thanks Dave that did answer my question if you could put that in an answer post and just link the URL I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: By reading all the answers, there is a lot more that is covered there IMO. Don't take it by the title or the first answer.